# Generic method to map objects of different types

Tags: c#

I would like to write Generic Method that would map List to new list, similar to JS's map method. I would then use this method like this:

```
var words= new List<string>() { "Kočnica", "druga beseda", "tretja", "izbirni", "vodno bitje" };
List<object> wordsMapped = words.Map(el => new { cela = el, končnica = el.Končnica(5) });
```

I know there's Select method which does the same thing but I need to write my own method. Right now I have this:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> SelectMy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seznam, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    List<object> ret = new List<object>();

    foreach (var el in seznam)
        ret.Add(predicate(el));

    return ret;
}
```

I also know I could use `yield return` but again I mustn't. I think the problem is with undeclared types and compiler can't figure out how it should map objects but I don't know how to fix that. All examples and tutorials I found map object of same types.

Comment: Do you just want to write an identical extension method to `Select`? Also, you seem to have a lot of odd hoops that you have to jump through. Can't use `Select`, can't use `yield return`... Is this some kind of assignment?

Comment: For future reference, if you're getting a compiler error you should post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq's `Select` is the equivalent of the `map()` function in other functional languages. The mapping function would typically not be called `Predicate`, IMO - predicate would be a filter which could reduce the collection.

You can certainly wrap an extension method which would apply a projection to map input to output (either of which could be be anonymous types):

```
public static IEnumerable<TO> Map<TI, TO>(this IEnumerable<TI> seznam, 
                                          Func<TI, TO> mapper)
{
    foreach (var item in seznam)
        yield return mapper(item);
}
```

Which is equivalent to

```
public static IEnumerable<TO> Map<TI, TO>(this IEnumerable<TI> seznam, 
                                          Func<TI, TO> mapper)
{
    return seznam.Select(mapper);
}
```

And if you don't want a strong return type, you can leave the output type as `object`

```
public static IEnumerable<object> Map<TI>(this IEnumerable<TI> seznam, Func<TI, object> mapper)
{
   // Same implementation as above
```

And called like so:

```
var words = new List<string>() { "Kočnica", "druga beseda", "tretja", "izbirni", "vodno bitje" };
var wordsMapped = words.Map(el => new { cela = el, končnica = el.Končnica(5) });
```

**Edit**
If you enjoy the runtime thrills of dynamic languages, you could also use `dynamic` in place of `object`.

But using `dynamic` like this so this [precludes the using the sugar](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter14/DynamicGotchas.aspx) of extension methods like `Končnica` - `Končnica` would either need to be a method on all of the types utilized, or be invoked explicitly, e.g.

```
static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int Končnica(this int i, int someInt)
    {
        return i;
    }

    public static Foo Končnica(this Foo f, int someInt)
    {
        return f;
    }

    public static string Končnica(this string s, int someInt)
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

And then, provided all items in your input implemented `Končnica` you could invoke:

```
var things = new List<object>
{ 
   "Kočnica", "druga beseda", 
    53, 
    new Foo() 
};

var mappedThings = things.Map(el => new 
{ 
     cela = el, 
     končnica = MyExtensions.Končnica(el, 5) 
     // Or el.Končnica(5) IFF it is a method on all types, else run time errors ...
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, you were first to answer so I accepted your answer even though other answers were as helpful as yours.

Comment: I would try and avoid use of `dynamic` - provided that your projections are all done on strong types, the strongly typed `<TI, TO>` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your code to work correctly like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMy<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> seznam, 
                                                        Func<T, TResult> mapping)
{
    var ret = new List<TResult>();

    foreach (var el in seznam)
    {
        ret.Add(mapping(el));
    }    

    return ret;
}
```

Note that this is inefficient and problematic compared to typical Linq extensions, because it enumerates the entire input at once. If the input is an infinite series, you are in for a bad time.

It is possible to remedy this problem without the use of `yield`, but it would be somewhat lengthy. I think it would be ideal if you could tell us all *why* you are trying to do this task with two hands tied behind your back.

---

As a bonus, here is how you could implement this with the lazy evaluation benefits of `yield` without actually using yield. This should make it abundantly clear just how valuable `yield` is:

```
internal class SelectEnumerable<TIn, TResult> : IEnumerable<TResult>
{
    private IEnumerable<TIn> BaseCollection { get; set; }
    private Func<TIn, TResult> Mapping { get; set; }

    internal SelectEnumerable(IEnumerable<TIn> baseCollection, 
                              Func<TIn, TResult> mapping)
    {
        BaseCollection = baseCollection;
        Mapping = mapping;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TResult> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new SelectEnumerator<TIn, TResult>(BaseCollection.GetEnumerator(), 
                                                  Mapping);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
}

internal class SelectEnumerator<TIn, TResult> : IEnumerator<TResult>
{
    private IEnumerator<TIn> Enumerator { get; set; }
    private Func<TIn, TResult> Mapping { get; set; }

    internal SelectEnumerator(IEnumerator<TIn> enumerator, 
                              Func<TIn, TResult> mapping)
    {
        Enumerator = enumerator;
        Mapping = mapping;
    }

    public void Dispose() { Enumerator.Dispose(); }

    public bool MoveNext() { return Enumerator.MoveNext(); }

    public void Reset() { Enumerator.Reset(); }

    public TResult Current { get { return Mapping(Enumerator.Current); } }

    object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }
}

internal static class MyExtensions
{
    internal static IEnumerable<TResult> MySelect<TIn, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TIn> enumerable,
        Func<TIn, TResult> mapping)
    {
        return new SelectEnumerable<TIn, TResult>(enumerable, mapping);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that [`Predicate<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a delegate that returns a boolean, which you're then trying to add to a `List<object>`.

Using a `Func<T,object>` is probably what you're looking for.

That being said, that code smells bad:

- Converting to `object` is less than useful
- Passing a delegate that maps `T` to an anonymous type won't help - you'll still get an `object` back which has no useful properties.
- You probably want to add a `TResult` generic type parameter to your method, and take a `Func<T, TResult>` as an argument.

Comment: I agree with all 3 points but the task was only to demonstrate usage of our own method to map List elements.