# Generic method to map different object

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I would like to create a generic method that can convert an object to a different type. I could not find any solutions for this scenario. Is this possible in C#?

```
class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class A1: A
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string DBName { get; set; }
    public string DBConnectionString { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    A obj = //data
    var res = APIToBackEndModel<A, B>(obj);

    //Do something
    A1 obj1 = //data
    var res1 = APIToBackEndModel<A1, B>(obj1);
}

private TResult APIToBackEndModel<T, TResult>(T objTo)
{
    (TResult)DBName = (T)objTo.Name;

    //OR

    var obj = new TResult
    {
        DBName = (T)objTo.Name
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718652/generic-method-to-map-objects-of-different-types) did not help me.

Comment: what are the `T` you want to use this with? do they all have a `Name`? would a common base-type or interface be useful? (generics supports constraints on the type parameters). What `TResult` do you need? basically, can we see some real examples?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually intending to use this function for?

Comment: @MarcGravell I updated the question

Comment: Are you looking for something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) or libraries like that?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing adding Automapper to project will it not be heavy for this functionality? it would be better for me to create two methods to map instead.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it *completely* generic, as you rely on certain properties to exist. But you knowing these properties exist, is not enough. You have to guarantee the compiler, they exist. You can do this with [Constraints on type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). With their help, you can define, that the generic types you use, will have certain properties (for instance implement an interface or inherit from a class).

```
interface InterfaceIn {
    string p1 {get;set;}

    void m1();
}

interface InterfaceOut {
     string p2 {get;set;}
     void m2();
}

class ConcreteIn : InterfaceIn {

    public string p1 {get;set;}
    public void m1() {}
}

class ConcreteOut1 : InterfaceOut {
    public string p2 {get;set;}
    public void m2() {}
}


class ConcreteOut2 : InterfaceOut {
    public string p2 {get;set;}
    public void m2() {}

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new ConcreteIn{p1 = "some value"};
        var b = mapIt<ConcreteIn, ConcreteOut1>(a);
        var c = mapIt<ConcreteIn, ConcreteOut2>(a);
    }

    public static V mapIt<U, V>(U val) where U: InterfaceIn where V: InterfaceOut, new() {
        var res = new V {p2 = val.p1};
        return res;
    }
}
```

Depending on how much properties and combinations you have, this *may* be enough. Or you may be better off with something like Automapper as Hans Keﬆing suggested. Or, if you can't group together some mappings, you will have to implement every mapping yourself.